# How can I prevent flashing?

Tags: java, swing, animation, graphics

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Racing extends JFrame {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -198172151996959655L;

//makes the screen size
final int WIDTH = 900, HEIGHT = 650;

//keeps track of player speed
double plSpeed = .5;

//numbers that represent direction
final int UP = 0, RIGHT = 1, DOWN = 2, LEFT = 3, STOP = 5, START = 6;

//keeps track of player direction
int p1Direction = START;

//makes player 1's car
Rectangle p1 = new Rectangle ( 100, 325, 30, 30 );
Rectangle foreground = new Rectangle( 500, 500, 200, 200 );

//constructor
public Racing() {
    //define defaults for the JFrame
    super ("Racing");
    setSize( WIDTH, HEIGHT );
    setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    //start the inner class
    Move1 m1 = new Move1();
    m1.start();
}

//draws the cars and race track
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    super.paint(g);
    //draw p1
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(p1.x,p1.y,p1.width,p1.height);
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillRect(foreground.x,foreground.y,foreground.width,foreground.height);

}
private class Move1 extends Thread implements KeyListener {
    public void run() {
        //makes the key listener "wake up"
        addKeyListener(this);

        //should be done in an infinite loop, so it repeats
        while (true) {
            //make try block, so it can exit if it errors
            try {
                //refresh screen
                repaint();

                //makes car increase speed a bit
                if (plSpeed <= 7) {
                    plSpeed += .2;
                }

                //lets the car stop
                if (plSpeed==0) {
                    p1Direction = STOP;
                }

                //moves player based on direction
                if (p1Direction==UP) {
                    p1.y -= (int) plSpeed;
                }
                if (p1Direction==DOWN) {
                    p1.y += (int) plSpeed;
                }
                if (p1Direction==LEFT) {
                    p1.x -= (int) plSpeed;
                }
                if (p1Direction==RIGHT) {
                    p1.x += (int) plSpeed;
                }
                if (p1Direction==STOP) {
                    plSpeed = 0;
                }

                //delays refresh rate
                Thread.sleep(75);

            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                //if an error, exit
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //have to input these (so it will compile)
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        try {
            //makes car increase speed a bit
            if (event.getKeyChar()=='w' ||
                event.getKeyChar()=='a' ||
                event.getKeyChar()=='s' ||
                event.getKeyChar()=='d') {
                    plSpeed += .2;
                    repaint();
            }
        } catch (Exception I) {}
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {}

    //now, to be able to set the direction
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
        if (plSpeed > 0) {
            if (event.getKeyChar()=='a') {
                if (p1Direction==RIGHT) {
                    p1Brake();
                } else {
                    if (p1Direction==LEFT) {
                    } else {
                        p1Direction = LEFT;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (event.getKeyChar()=='s') {
                if (p1Direction==UP) {
                    p1Brake();
                } else {
                    if (p1Direction==DOWN) {
                    } else {
                        p1Direction = DOWN;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (event.getKeyChar()=='d') {
                if (p1Direction==LEFT) {
                    p1Brake();
                } else {
                    if (p1Direction==RIGHT) {
                    } else {
                        p1Direction = RIGHT;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (event.getKeyChar()=='w') {
                if (p1Direction==DOWN) {
                    p1Brake();
                } else {
                    if (p1Direction==UP) {
                    } else {
                        p1Direction = UP;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (event.getKeyChar()=='z') {
                p1Brake();
            }
        }
    }

    public void p1Brake () {
        try {
            while (plSpeed != 0) {
                plSpeed -= .2;
                Thread.sleep(75);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            plSpeed = 0;
        }
    }
}

//finally, to start the program
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Racing frame = new Racing();
    frame.setVisible( true );
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
    frame.setResizable( false );
}
```

}

This is an SSCCE of my code. If I add super.paint(g); to the top of this, inside the class, then it gets all flashy. If I leave that out, then whenever you move the player, then it creates a line of where the player has been-without repainting. I need to know how to - and where to repaint. The closest I have gotten to my answer here here:

http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/37406-repaint-without-flashing.html

but they have an applet (which I have never dealt with before, and assuming it would be rather tricky to translate the code from applet to frames). Can anybody help me with this?

Notes:

I didn't know you could make a frame with awt, because I was happy and familiar with swing, so I didn't want to change. Sorry about that. As you can see, whatever i draw flashes, not just the player.

Andrew, here's my screenshot:
[image: the game]

Oh, and it doesn't register P2.

Comment: What happened to *"I'll make sure to do that next time."* from [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889977/how-do-i-set-an-image-in-a-rectangle).  I don't see an SSCCE, only uncompilable code snippets where you cannot even tell if Swing or AWT is used. -1

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit confused- and therefore misguided- on the definition of SSCCE. i'll be able to post one tomarrow.

Comment: There, this demonstrates my problem.

Comment: Now *that* is an SSCCE!  :)  See my answer, I think I fixed most of the problem.  One note:  **Never** `Thread.sleep(n)` on the EDT, even when `p1Brake`ing.  ;)

Comment: *"I was happy and familiar with swing, so I didn't want to change."*  Stick with Swing components.  It is a newer more powerful toolkit, and much easier to get answers on (most of the people who used AWT components have forgotten the details).

Comment: You should NOT be overriding the paint() method of the JFrame. See [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for explanation and example.

Comment: Okay, i guess i'll stick with swing. And camickr, do you mean leave out the @override command?

Comment: It is generally held that is best ***not*** to override the painting methodology of top-level containers like `JFrame`, `JApplet` or `JWindow`.  There are a number of good reasons for this (better dealt with on a separate question).   Instead you can override the painting of a `JComponent` or `JPanel` and **add that** to any of the above.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Racing UI]

I made a number of changes.  Here are some I can recall.

1. Refactored custom painting from top-level container to `JPanel`, and moved painting to `paintComponent()`.
2. Removed `Thread` and `Thread.sleep(n)` & replaced with a `Timer`/`ActionListener`.
3. Constructed the GUI on the EDT.
4. Removed setting the size of the `JFrame`.  Instead sets a preferred size for the `JPanel` (the actual drawing area) and calls `JFrame.pack()` to get the correct overall size.
5. Uses `setLocationByPlatform(true)` instead of the [very splash-screen like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556) `setLocationRelativeTo(null)`.

Check the code carefully for further tips.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Racing extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -198172151996959655L;

//keeps track of player speed
double plSpeed = .5;

//numbers that represent direction
final int UP = 0, RIGHT = 1, DOWN = 2, LEFT = 3, STOP = 5, START = 6;

//keeps track of player direction
int p1Direction = START;

//makes player 1's car
Rectangle p1 = new Rectangle ( 100, 25, 30, 30 );

//constructor
public Racing() {
    //define defaults for the JFrame
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    //makes the screen size
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,50));

    //makes the key listener "wake up"
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);

    ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            //refresh screen
            repaint();

            //makes car increase speed a bit
            if (plSpeed <= 7) {
                plSpeed += .2;
            }

            //lets the car stop
            if (plSpeed==0) {
                p1Direction = STOP;
            }

            //moves player based on direction
            if (p1Direction==UP) {
                p1.y -= (int) plSpeed;
            }
            if (p1Direction==DOWN) {
                p1.y += (int) plSpeed;
            }
            if (p1Direction==LEFT) {
                p1.x -= (int) plSpeed;
            }
            if (p1Direction==RIGHT) {
                p1.x += (int) plSpeed;
            }
            if (p1Direction==STOP) {
                plSpeed = 0;
            }
        }
    };

    Timer t = new Timer(75,al);
    t.start();
}

//draws the cars and race track
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    //draw p1
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(p1.x,p1.y,p1.width,p1.height);

}

//have to input these (so it will compile)
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
    System.out.println(event);
    try {
        //makes car increase speed a bit
        if (event.getKeyChar()=='w' ||
            event.getKeyChar()=='a' ||
            event.getKeyChar()=='s' ||
            event.getKeyChar()=='d') {
                plSpeed += .2;
                //repaint();
        }
    } catch (Exception I) {}
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {}

//now, to be able to set the direction
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
    if (plSpeed > 0) {
        if (event.getKeyChar()=='a') {
            if (p1Direction==RIGHT) {
                p1Brake();
            } else {
                if (p1Direction==LEFT) {
                } else {
                    p1Direction = LEFT;
                }
            }
        }
        if (event.getKeyChar()=='s') {
            if (p1Direction==UP) {
                p1Brake();
            } else {
                if (p1Direction==DOWN) {
                } else {
                    p1Direction = DOWN;
                }
            }
        }
        if (event.getKeyChar()=='d') {
            if (p1Direction==LEFT) {
                p1Brake();
            } else {
                if (p1Direction==RIGHT) {
                } else {
                    p1Direction = RIGHT;
                }
            }
        }
        if (event.getKeyChar()=='w') {
            if (p1Direction==DOWN) {
                p1Brake();
            } else {
                if (p1Direction==UP) {
                } else {
                    p1Direction = UP;
                }
            }
        }
        if (event.getKeyChar()=='z') {
            p1Brake();
        }
    }
}

public void p1Brake () {
    try {
        while (plSpeed != 0) {
            plSpeed -= .2;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        plSpeed = 0;
    }
}

//finally, to start the program
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFrame f = new JFrame("Racing");
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
            f.add(new Racing());
            f.pack();
            f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            f.setResizable( false );
            f.setVisible( true );
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Oh and there is one more thing I'm confused about: what is an EDT?

Comment: Well, I implemented these changes into my game code, and unfortunatly forgot to save my old code, in case it didn't work- and it didn't. I still get the same trail, but the computer does not recognize rectangles are overlapping, and the speed is all screwed up. If you're interested, I can send you my full current code. I am putting a screenshot of it in my question.

Answer (score 1):

You should never attempt to draw directly onto the canvas, use a background thread that keeps the next frame ready always and swap it with the old one.

```
    while (state == RUNNING)
    {
        long beforeTime = System.nanoTime();
        gEngine.update(); // update stuff like game score life etc..

        Canvas c = null;
        try
        {
            c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
            synchronized (mSurfaceHolder)
            {                   
                drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 600);
                drawable.draw(c); // flash new background if required for the new frame
                gEngine.draw(c);    // update game state
            }
        } finally
        {
            if (c != null)
            {
                mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }

        this.sleepTime = delay
                - ((System.nanoTime() - beforeTime) / 1000000L);

        try
        {
            if (sleepTime > 0)
            {
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(PaintThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                    null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: aahhh good idea. Now, to figure out how to do that. I'll sleep on it, then come back to you tomorrow.

Comment: Problem is this is an AWT code suggestion which won't work in Swing which is what the posters last question was based on. Until the post learns to post an SSCCE which was also recommended in his last posting we are just guessing. The poster hasn't even copied the painting code from the posting he referenced in his question.

Comment: The only thing different with painting is adding the line "super.paint(g)", which I mentioned in my question and didn't think it was worthwile to put in my code again. I posted as little as I thought possible without leaving out the painting code. It looks like there is a little confusion on this- I am using swing.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the code from applet to JFrame is not hard at all.
Rename the class's extension to JPanel:

`public class Racing extends JPanel`

then in the method where you instantiate a new Racing
change it to instantiate a new JFrame
and any method in racing like `setTitle(...)` that now throws an error move to the method that instantiates the new JFrame, as `(whatever you named the JFrame reference).setTitle(...)`
Then apply the following code to the rest of the JFrame:

```
JFrame.add(new Racing());
JFrame.setSize(*the size of Racing window*);
```